# Move merge commit (first commit of branch)

Tags: git

I currently have a repo in this state:

```
…a——b——c——d——e BranchA
      \
…h——i——m——n——o BranchC
    ^  
    |  
BranchB Head
```

and would like to get this state:

```
…a——b——c——d——e BranchA
              \
…h——i——————————m——n——o BranchC
    ^  
    |  
BranchB Head
```

I know how to rebase branches to move commits, but I only want to "rebase" BranchC, **not BranchB**.

How would I do that ?

Comment: Merge `e` into `i` then rebase `n` and `o` on top of the new commit. Discard the old `m`, `n` and `o`.

Comment: @axiac write as an answer? Also, rebasing will make `n` and `o` unreachable so they'll effectively be "discarded".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want is not achievable using `rebase` only. In the initial state, commit `m` has two parents: `b` and `i`. In the desired state is has different parents: `e` and `i`. In fact, `m` in the desired state is a completely different commit than `m` in the initial state.

Merge `e` into `i` then rebase `n` and `o` on top of the new commit. Discard the old `m`, `n` and `o`.

You can run these commands:

```
# Create a backup branch on commit `o` 
# It is useful to restore the original status of the repo if something goes wrong
$ git branch backupC BranchC

# Create a working branch on commit `i` and check it out
$ git checkout -b work BranchB

# Merge `e` into `i`
$ git merge BranchA

# Rebase the last 2 commits of BranchC on top of the new branch
$ git rebase --onto work BranchC~2 BranchC
```

That's all. The current branch is `BranchC` now. If you are pleased with the result you can now remove the branches `backup` and `work`:

```
$ git branch -D backup work
```

When the `backup` branch is deleted, the old commits `m`, `n` and `o` become unreachable.

But if something goes wrong (conflicts) and `git merge` or `git rebase` cannot complete you can abort the process and restore the initial state by running `git rebase --abort` or `git merge --abort` (depending on the command that failed) then:

```
# Move branch `BranchC` to its initial position (commit `o`)
$ git branch -f BranchC backup

# Restore the original HEAD
$ git checkout BranchB

# Remove the branches created during the process
$ git branch -D backup work
```

Comment: That works fine. I was just missing the initial merge. The rebase allows me to resolve conflicts commit by commit, that's perfect. Thanks !